# JAXB Unmarshalling with outer and inner tags having same name and different attributes

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

```
   <xyz>
      <a attributeA, AttributeB>
        <b> </b>
        <c>
            <a attribute1,attribute2,attribute3/>
        </c>
     </a>
  </xyz>
```

can anyone suggest me how to deal with 'a' innertag.

Comment: Just map the outer and inner As to different classes, but set the name value in the @XmlElement annotations accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find [JAXB annotations](https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.4/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElements.html) easier.

```
@XMLElement
xyz.A a;
```

Probably in another bean class:

```
@XMLElement(name = "a")
xyz.c.A suba;
```